# Finite dimensional subspace of Hilbert space and basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be infinite-dimensional Hilbert space with basis functions $b_i$.

Let $B_n = \text{span}\{b_1,  ...,b_n\}$.

So $\text{dim}(N) = n$.

Let $c_i$ be another basis for $H$. Is it true that
$$B_n = \text{span}\{c_{j_1}, ..., c_{j_n}\}$$
for some indices ${j_i}$?

I think so since $B_n$ has dimension $n$ so anything in the set can be written as sum of $n$ basis functions?

Comment: No, that need not be. Consider $n = 1$ for simple counterexamples.

Comment: Please see my answer in this question:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430211/question-about-bases-in-hilbert-spaces-and-subspaces/430220#430220

Comment: @ShuhaoCao Nice answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not even true for finite-dimensional spaces. Let $B = \mathrm{span}(e_1) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ and look at the basis $c_1 = (1,1)$, $c_2 = (1,-1)$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$.